# Роли пользователей для созданий ограничений

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть сайт онлайн банк. Надо создать роли: клиент, менеджер (банкир), администратор.

Как создать роли для пользователей, чтобы можно как-то запрещать доступ к маршруту или наоборот разрешать?

Для клиента банка часть служебной информации надо закрыть и оставить эту информацию только для менеджера

Comment: Роберт, а где ваш вариант решения ?

Comment: Я не решение жду, какую функцию использовать или что-то в этом духе

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. О чём речь, про какой вы написали маршрут ? Чтобы разрешить или запретить, нужно понимать, о какой программе, объекте или классе вы говорите, я пока не понял. Нужно больше разъяснений

Comment: У меня есть сайт онлайн банк, роли: клиент, менеджер(банкир), администратор. Для клиента вьюха с какой-то служебной информацией надо закрыть, только для менеджера. LoginMixin проверяет только зарегистрирован пользователь или нет

Comment: Попробую перенести эту информацию в заголовок вопроса

Comment: Уже нельзя изменить вопрос

Comment: Вы можете задать новый вопрос, а этот оставьте так, как есть